# Hover div in div

Tags: html, css

I have two divs with the same class which I can't change. One div is the parent of the over one. I want them to have a hovereffekt, but if I hover the child, the hover of the parent should go away.
The divs are created automatically by extjs and it can be 2 or even more.

```
<div class="x-test-container">
    <div class="x-test-container">
         <div class="x-test-container">
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So if i hover the inner child, i want the parents to have no hovereffekt. Can someone help me?

Comment: can you give css?

Comment: you can specify CSS. try to use `.class>.class` it will work the only for firstly nested element to this class, however since it's a twice nesting, you can access the only last one.

Comment: Also, you can do it using JavaScript where is it will be easier to specify element you need, because you could work with second. But you'll need the `eventListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".x-test-container").mouseover(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    //set the background color to desired color on mouseover
   $(this).css('background', 'green');
  });
  
  $(".x-test-container").mouseout(function(event) {
    //set the background color to desired color on mouseout
   $(this).css('background', 'transparent');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="x-test-container">
  <div class="x-test-container">
    <div class="x-test-container">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks great! We are using extjs and not jquery but I think I can translate that ;) Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.x-test-container').last().css('background', 'green');
  jQuery('.x-test-container').last().hover(function() {
    jQuery('.x-test-container').last().css('background', 'red');
  });
  jQuery('.x-test-container').last().mouseout(function() {
    jQuery('.x-test-container').last().css('background', 'green');
  });

});
```

```css
div {
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="x-test-container">
  <div class="x-test-container">
    <div class="x-test-container">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```